# exponent of the powerlaw distribution and Barabasi-Albert-Model; value of the exponent

Tags: probability, python

I am new to studying the scale-free networks and applying it to Microbial communities for research work which include Barabasi-Albert-Model. In the course of the study, I came across the degree distribution which follows power-law from study on the https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9910332 by Albert and Barabsi(1999). I don't know how to calculate or measure and compare the value of $\alpha$ from the equation  $p(x) $~$ cx^{-\alpha}$.

Secondly, $$
\alpha=1+n\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\frac{x_i}{x_{min}}\right]^{-1}.$$

1. I tried using the equation above to obtain the value of $\alpha$ with respect to $p(x) $~$ cx^{-\alpha}$,  but still couldn't obtain the value of $\alpha$ for an estimation against the degree of distribution on the graph.
2. From Barabasi article (1999), for the citation and power grid date, how are the values of gamma obtained to be 2.3 and 4? Note, '$\gamma$' can be used in the place of '$\alpha$' from the equation.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of context. First part is more or less OK, I can make a guess of what you want. For the second part, what do you want after you calculate $\alpha$ from the formula? Also, I have no idea who Barabasi is, or where to find his article.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the your response. For the Barabasi-Albert-Model (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9910332), you can get the article there. I need to get the values of $\alpha$ because this will help me obtain the value of the exponent of the power-law and understand the degree of Distribution. How can you help me with the first part?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You need to edit your post, add what you've tried, add citations, and be more clear about your intent. Otherwise, you may find your question closed, and people may not be interested in trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from your definition of the power law distribution: $p(x)=cx^{-\alpha}$, that is valid from some $x_{min}$. First we want to calculate $c$. We know that the integrated probability is $1$. $$1=c\int_{x_{min}}^\infty x^{-\alpha}dx=c\frac{x_{min}^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1}$$
$$c=\frac{\alpha-1}{x_{min}^{1-\alpha}}$$
We can therefore write $$p(x)=\frac{\alpha-1}{x_{min}}\left(\frac{x}{x_{min}}\right)^{-\alpha}$$
There is a nice [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/probability-concepts-explained-maximum-likelihood-estimation-c7b4342fdbb1) that explains the concept of log likelihood. It boils down to this: the probability of getting $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ is$$\cal L(\alpha,x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=p(x_1)p(x_2)...p(x_n)$$
You want to take the derivative with respect to $\alpha$, such that you maximize the likelihood. This is a little tedious, so you can consider $\ln \cal L$ instead, You can do that since the logarithmic function is monotonic, so a maximum of $\cal L$ occurs at the same position $\ln\cal L$.
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln\cal L&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln\frac{\alpha-1}{x_{min}}\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{min}}\right)^{-\alpha}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac 1{\alpha-1}-\ln\frac{x_i}{x_{min}}\right)\\&=0\end{align}$$
From here $$\frac n{\alpha-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\frac{x_i}{x_{min}}$$
A simple re-arrangement of terms give you the initial formula.

**Note** a simple way to get $\alpha$, without requiring that the function is normalized, is to take the logarithm of the initial form of the distribution.
$$\ln p(x)=c-\alpha \ln x$$
You can see that in the log-log coordinates this is the equation of a straight line with slope $-\alpha$. Just do some linear fit to get $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant reply. However, how do I do a linear fit to get $\alpha$. I am trying to run a python code for this and that's if I am able to obtain a linear fit as $\alpha$ you have suggested.

Comment: So you have a few $(x_i, y_i)$ points. And you want to fit to $y=cx^{-\alpha}$. Like I've mentioned, write $Y_i=\ln y_i$ and $X_i=\ln x_i$. Then you fit $(X_i, Y_i)$ with the function $Y=a X+b$. Then $c=b$ and $\alpha = -a$. You can use directly a formula to combine logs and linear fitting. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPowerLaw.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. It became clearer.

Comment: Did it work? You are welcome. If you find the answer useful, don't forget to vote and/or mark it as accepted.